# How to make a Search Bar with an advanced filter search feature in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, searchbar, advanced-filter

I want to make a search bar for an app with an advanced filter feature in Flutter.
the UI will have a search bar and an advanced filter icon beside it so that you can refine your search.

The filter consist of these categories:

1. Subjects
2. Days
3. Hours

subjects here mean the subject or lesson that a tutor can teach. (Mathematics, Biology, etc.)
Day of the week means the availability day of a tutor on the week. (Sunday, Monday, etc.)
Hours of the day means the availability hour of a tutor on the day. (9-11 am, 5-7 pm)

I can't wrap my mind around how to develop the functionality.

By the way, I'm still a newbie in Flutter, and sorry for my English.

I tried searching on Google, StackOverflow, GitHub, and even ChatGPT but I still can't manage to find the one I want.

I read about using Chip choices and filter_list but I don't understand how.

I wanted it to be that the user can search for a tutor based on what subject they want to learn, at what day of the week, and at what time of the day.

For the time filter. I have been thinking about making a slider or something so the user can decide how long they want the tutoring to be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.